# How to get and assign data for each row

Tags: php, mysql

So what i am trying to do is to get data from database and assign it for each process to allow user edit it. 
Thats how I want it to look like:
[attached image][1]

But what I get is [here][2].
So as you can see it repeatedly displays on both processes.
So to get data and assign it to each process im doing this:

```
<div class="procLeader">
<div class="ui-widget-content">
<label>Leader:</label>  
  <ol>
    <li class="placeholder" name="procLeader[]"><div class="adding">Add Process Leader here</div></li>                          
    <?php   
        $result4 = getProcessLeader($projectNo);
        if (!$result4) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }   
        while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result4))
        {  
            $procL[] = $row4['process'];
            $procLeader[] = $row4['proc_leader'];
        }

        foreach( $procL as $proc => $eq ) 
        {
            $leader = $procLeader[$proc];
            echo "<li class='dropClass'><span class='closer'>x</span>".$leader."</li>";                                 
        }                           
    ?>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
```

And `getProcessLeader` function:

```
function getProcessLeader($projectNo){
    global $con;    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `proc_leader` WHERE projectNo='$projectNo' ";
    return mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

So how can I assign each person for exactly process? Thanks

## EDIT

After using only while, i still got problem with names displaying for each process:[Now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xLnV.png)

```
<div class="procLeader">
<div class="ui-widget-content">
<label>Leader:</label>  
  <ol>
    <li class="placeholder" name="procLeader[]"><div class="adding">Add Process Leader here</div></li>                          
    <?php   
        $result4 = getProcessLeader($projectNo);
        if (!$result4) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }   
        while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result4))
        {  
            $procL[] = $row4['process'];
            //$procLeader[] = $row4['proc_leader'];

            echo "<li class='dropClass'><span class='closer'>x</span>".$row4['proc_leader']."</li>";
        }

    ?>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
```

But I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aghye.png)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have two loops here, you probably only need the one. If you keep building on the two arrays without resetting it, you are likely experiencing the result of that. Try just echoing in the `while`.

```
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){  
    echo "<li class='dropClass'><span class='closer'>x</span>".$row4['proc_leader']."</li>";
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem for one repetition. But it still prints both of the names for each process. Please see edit. Thank you

Comment: You must have another loop that wraps what you have posted?

Comment: Not sure how to do it, that's why I posted here. I cant get how to do so each name will be displayed for assigned process

Comment: No I mean, do you have a loop that is wrapping this? You must because in your post you have `<label>Leader:</label>` once in the html but in your photo, you have two of those labels.

Comment: Yes it is a loop. Ok so it is a 2 step form, first form allows user to choose number of processes, second form allows user to assign people to each process. After submitting the form if user wants to edit project and pressing edit button I want to display this form with assigned processes and people inside it. My problem is that system displays all assigned names for each process. even if people assigned for different processes. It just displays all the data from database table

Comment: Well it sounds like a query issue perhaps now. Have you seen what the query is writing? Maybe the id is empty or something. You have to make sure the query is what you expect. Just echo it

Comment: Got it, thanks for an idea. Changed my query and now it works